# LINQ Statement to get most recent order from single customer

Tags: c#, linq

I'm learning Linq so please bear with me.
I am trying to create a Linq statement that get the most recent order from a single customer.  I tried the following but it seems a bit off:

```
CustOrder tempOrder = Orders
    .OrderByDescending(c => c.OrderDate)
    .Where(c => c.CustomerName == "ACME")
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Am I thinking correctly here?  Also if I wanted to get the oldest order would I just do this:

```
CustOrder tempOrder = Orders
    .OrderBy(c => c.OrderDate)
    .Where(c => c.CustomerName == "ACME")
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

I was reading about GroupBy and am a bit confused if it is applicable in my situation.
Thank you

Comment: I'm sorry Orders is a List<CustOrder>

Comment: so what result are you getting now? and what do you expect instead?

Comment: You can just edit your question to reflect that.

Comment: I'ld invert the `Where` and `OrderByDescending` order. First filter, then order the filtered enumerable.

Comment: What is wrong with what you have? How is it *"a bit off"*?

Comment: @Jimi does it really matters? EF automatically creates SQL. I dont think that order  
 of OrderBy will cause  problem here

Comment: What Jimi said is good advice, if you do Order or OrderByDescending, you have to process the entire list. This can be very expensive for big collections. If you filter with .Where first, then you can Order or OrderByDescending that smaller collection which will speed up your code. 

Also, for the sake of reusing code, you can use the same OrderBy and get either FirstOrDefault or LastOrDefault to get the min-max

Comment: GroupBy is normally for when you want aggregated data about something. Orderby is fine in your case.

Comment: @Simonare  I don't see a reference to Entity Framework. The OP is using a `List<class>`, apparently.

Comment: No, It does not do what you are saying since the query is still IQueryable. If you do     `Orders.OrderByDescending(c => c.OrderDate).ToList().FirstOrDefault()` then this will be expensive query

Comment: @Jimi, in this case it is not good to make this discussion here since we dont know the underlaying context, and since the OP is new on this subject and he dont know the difference between IQueryable and IList

Comment: @Simonare  I wasn't interpreting it as a discussion, just an exchange of points of view. Maybe the OP will be *inspired* and add some more details to the question.

Comment: @Simonare You may want to read up on how LINQ to Objects has to implement `OrderBy` (think about it - what if the last object in the `IEnumerable` (`List<CustOrder>`) is the first in the ordered sequence...

Comment: Thank you all for more insight into Linq.  There were 2 orders placed at the exact time.  (Milliseconds is not in the DateTime).  So the order I was actually expecting to see was not the order that was returning.  I was reading up on .Reverse() so I ended up using Simonare suggestion with a slight modification and it worked by adding Reverse.  Basically the records were coming from a text file that I parsed through and placed in a list.  Part of the problem may have been is that the text file they gave me had most recent orders at top of file descending to older orders.

Answer (score 0):

My apologies if am wrong here, but am curious by the Title of the question here. 
@7VNT - Do you mean, you want to get First and Last Order of Each Customer ? Is that why you were referring to GroupBy ?

In  which case, you do the following.

```
var firstOrders = Orders.GroupBy(x=>x.CustomerName)
                 .Select(c => c.OrderBy(x=>x.OrderDate).First());

var lastOrders = Orders.GroupBy(x=>x.CustomerName)
                .Select(c => c.OrderByDescending(x=>x.OrderDate).First());
```

Answer (score -1):

you can shorten your code like

```
CustOrder tempOrder = Orders
.OrderByDescending(c => c.OrderDate)
.FirstOrDefault(c => c.CustomerName == "ACME");
```

The rest of your code is ok. You can also do this:

```
IList<CustOrder> tempOrder = Orders
.OrderByDescending(c => c.OrderDate)
.Take(1).ToList();
```

this returns you a list but with one record.

Comment: I stated that (last sentence)

Comment: My comment was more about the type you've specified in the code...shouldn't it be a `List<CustOrder>`?

Comment: Oh I am sorry I forgot to modify that part. thank you for your comment